# Non closed connected subgroup of $SU(3)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I’m working on a problem which asks me to show there exist non closed connected subgroup of $SU(3)$. I believe there should be some well-known standard example for this and I would like to remember such an example. If not, then I really have no clues on how to prove this by contradictions, since the only lemma I know about this is a sufficient condition which said maximal abelian Lie sub algebra corresponds to a unique closed connected subgroup. Please give some advices, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look the section headed "Non-example" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group